# password_hash and remembering passwords for login

Tags: php, encryption, hash, remember-me, password-hash

Today I learned about secure hashing with salt at school and started using password_hash. It is amazing and it seems very secure, before this I was using md5 stuff. But now I'm missing something.

In my database I stored the login sessions and those who chose to "remember" their username and password. Then based on the IP and whether the last record has "yes" or "no" for the "remember" column in the database, I would decrypt the md5 of the password and use it as "value" for the password input. But decryption (as far as I know) is not possible for password_hash, you can only verify it, right? So, how would you go to implement the "remember password" option with password_hash?

Comment: decryption of `md5` is "technically" not possible either ... so with out your code we can not help you.

Comment: You store a `key` in a `cookie`, and you store that same `key`with the user `id` in a database. Then, if they load your page, you can check if they have a matching code. In that manner you can check if it's the same browser/device going on your site.

Answer (score 3):

Just to avoid misunderstandings, the remember-me functionallity has nothing to do with the user password, it would be a serious security breach if you stored the password client-side.

Usually, after a successful login, the application:

1. generates a *random token* which is independend of username or password.
2. This token can then be set in a cookie on the client side.
3. A hash of the token is stored in the database, together with the userid.
4. If the user visits the site the next time, instead of asking for the password, one can read the token from the cookie, hash it again and compare it with the already stored token.
5. If the hashes match, the user is allowed to access the site without entering the username and password.

Comment: `Usually, after a successful login, the application generates a random token `, You mean only first login? or after every login would generate new token?

Comment: @OTARIKI - Create a new token whenever the user logged in and requested a remember-me cookie (this should be optional of course). After the user logged out, the token shouldn't be valid anymore, so you generate another one the next time. There could also be several tokens for several devices.

Comment: bravo! Thanks alot man

Answer (score 0):

In general, the function you're looking for is `password_verify()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

But just set a session variable or something to remember the user, no need to do anything with decrypting passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The remember me functionality uses cookies, so a hash is stored at the client site as well as on your server site basically in the user database next to the users password hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decrypt a hashed password(at least in theory). That's the whole reason it's secure. On the server side you need a way to log in a user without needing a password. Just bypass the part where you would check the password if the "remember me" part checks out fine.

As a side not ip address isn't really a great way to remember a user's session. Several computers behind a NAT might appear to have the same IP to the server. Look into using cookies instead.